# Configuration error : No Session found for current thread with spring, hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, configuration

I'm using springframework 3.4, hibernate 4.3

I want to separate hibernate configuration and mvc dispatch configuration from mvc-config.xml.

mvc-config.xml -> mvc-config.xml + applicationContext.xml

After separation.....

1) When I start the app I couldn't find about this log:

```
INFO org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect:org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
INFO o.h.e.t.i.TransactionFactoryInitiator - HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
INFO o.h.h.i.a.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory ........
INFO o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager - Using DataSource [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@14f205ce] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
```

It seems that WAS cannot read dataSource and sessionFactory

2) In website, shows me "HTTP Status 500 about org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread"

This is how i had configured

web.xml - pasted partly about loading contexts

```
.............................................
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
............................................
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

mvc-config.xml

```
<context:annotation-config />

<context:component-scan  base-package="com.mtm.mes"/>

<mvc:annotation-driven />


<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value=""/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>


<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>
```

applicationContext.xml (created new from mvc-config.xml)

```
<context:annotation-config />

<context:component-scan  base-package="com.mtm.mes"/>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.mtm.mes" />        
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:INTRA" />
    <property name="username" value="mes" />
    <property name="password" value="mes" />
    <property name="maxWait" value="1000"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="10"/>
    <property name="maxIdle" value="1"/>        
    <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>
    <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="30"/>
    <property name="logAbandoned" value="true"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1 from dual" />
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
    <property name="testOnReturn" value="true" />  
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="transactionManager"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Can anyone help??

Comment: You are duplicating your package-scan. Both the `DispatcherServlet` and `ContextLoaderListener` have the same `component-scan`. This leads to bean duplication for all of your beans, basically rendering all your beans in the `ContextLoaderListener` useless (i.e. no aop applied).

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for the reply. I made a solution. In web.xml <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml</param-value> to <param-value></param-value> and deleted mvc-config.xml and added mvc-config.xml to applicationContext.xml. So I roll back to one configuration xml, it works.